# Como funciona internamente Workbench de MYSQL

Tags: sql

Estoy buscando informacion como funciona SQL. Quisiera saber que algoritmo utiliza para hacer la busqueda del dato apartir de una SELECT. 
Ejemplo: Select nombre from clientes; como hace internamente para sacarte la lista de los nombres de los clientes.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench no realiza la búsqueda. Se conecta al MySQL Server, que es el que ejecuta la búsqueda (con la query que escribas en mysql workbench), y devuelve un conjunto de resultados. El workbench sólo pasa la query al motor, y pinta la respuesta "bonita".

Respecto a tu pregunta de los algoritmos, cada motor de base de datos está construido y pensado de forma distinta, y seguramente los fabricantes no rebelen ese tipo de informacion para no facilitar el trabajo a la competencia. Pero seguro que hay información en líneas generales de los algoritmos que buscas.

Comment: Por favor no respondas a preguntas mal planteadas pues terminan cerradas, de hecho le falta un voto para eso